# freopen() in C causing an infinite loop!

Tags: c

I am using freopen() function in C to read data from a file **Data.txt** and write the same data to an output file **Output.txt** .This is the code I am writing to do this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,diff,number_of_inputs,num1,num2;
    freopen("Data.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("Output.txt","w",stdout);
    scanf("%d",&number_of_inputs);
    for(i=0;i<number_of_inputs;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
        printf("%d %d",num1,num2);  
    }
    fclose(stdin);
    fclose(stdout);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The **Data.txt** file contains:
3
10 12
10 14
100 200

But the output file contains a large volume of **garbage numbers** giving an impression of an infinite loop.Can someone tell me whats going wrong?

Comment: You should probably print `number_of_inputs` before using it. Doing simple debugging tasks would be far easier if you change away from `freopen(3)` and replace `scanf(3)` and `printf(3)` will `fscanf(3)` and `fprintf(3)` calls -- then you can use simple `printf("num: %d\n", number_of_inputs);` and see just how far you're looping. :)

Comment: I've tried running your code on my Ubuntu box, having commented out `#include<conio.h>` and `getch();` and it works as expected.

Comment: @sarnold It shows 
Number of input = 22936722 49.Can anyone rationalise this strangeness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run your code through a debugger.  I think then it'll probably be blindingly obvious what the issue is.

Having said that, you do **no** error checking on any of your library calls.  If any of them fail, you'll just have garbage values in your variables.

Answer (score 2):

Your code needs to check the return values from `freopen()` and `scanf()`.

An unexpected return value from either of those functions will give you clues as to what is going wrong.

`freopen()` returns `NULL` to indicate an error.

`scanf()` returns the number of items converted, or `EOF`.

In either case your code can examine the value of `errno` to find out what caused the error. You will probably want to print it using `perror()`.

Comment: I checked the freopen function for NULL return value.It seems to work fine.But my **Output.txt** file gets filled up with these numbers 2088763392 2088810217 a lot of times showing that somewhere its having an infinite loop.

Comment: You need to check the return value for `scanf()` as well. The first call will return 1 if it works, the call in the loop should return 2.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the lack of newlines, that seems to run fine on my machine - the output is `10 1210 14100 200`, which when appropriately newlined, gives

```
10 12
10 14
100 200
```

.

Also, `getch()` is a strange choice, given that you've just called `fclose()` on `stdin`